# Is ISO8859-15 (Latin-9) a full subselect of UTF-8?

Tags: oracle, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages, iso-8859-15

I might need to convert an Oracle DB from ISO8859-15 (Latin-9) to UTF-8? So my question is: Is  ISO8859-15 (Latin-9) a full subset of UTF-8?

Because than there should be a lower risk of things going wrong.
Any experience here?

Comment: No, `UTF-8`  was designed for backward compatibility with `ASCII` (the first 128 characters of Unicode. Whatever above is UTF-8 encoded using *two to four* one-byte code units). BTW, always perform a full backup before experimenting…

Comment: Every supported codepoint that maps to ISO-8859-15 is supported by UTF-8, because UTF-8 supports all Unicode codepoints.